# How can we fix the bad hover image (on Questions link in meta and main)?

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, design

When you hover over "Questions" (in both main and meta) there is a tiny little yellow (or grey) line that shouldn't be there down the bottom, which irritates the graphical pedant in me. How to fix?

I'm not trying to be totally trivial here. I hope I learn more about how SEs are administrated from the inside by asking this question.

Image zoomed to double. Could be hard to see on certain monitors, but the green arrow is there to help!

**Fixed** as at 4 January 2012.

[image: Image of Questions link with trailing yellow line]

Comment: Our [css](http://vimeo.com/3718294) master [Jin](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/users/7/jin) is on vacation, but I'll email him this, just to disrupt his ramen-eating.

Comment: Can you removed the status-completed tag, @yoda, because the bug still exists! I can't seem to remove it. Cheers

Comment: @Lisa Done. I added it only because you said that it was fixed... I can't really tell the difference. I guess I'll really wait for Jin to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought it had been fixed but it hasn't. It's not visible for me in Chrome and IE, but in FF7 I still see this problem and I know why now. See http://cdn.sstatic.net/Skins/sketchymeta/img/sprites-beta.png and http://cdn.sstatic.net/Skins/sketchy/img/sprites-beta.png. The hover image for "Questions" gets the very top line of pixels from the background scribble below it, and it's probably a browser-specific issue because Firefox does something or other differently with spacing. This also may be why nobody raised it yet. It's probably not visible to many due to browser choice.

Comment: I have just noticed this has been fixed. Someone shaved a little bit of the http://cdn.sstatic.net/Skins/sketchymeta/img/sprites-beta.png image to make it work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You must either have a very good eye or a very good monitor (or both!). I had to strain my eyes to see it on my monitor. In any case, all the beta sites get this "sketchy" theme, which *deliberately* looks like a rough, hastily done, imperfect looking theme to indicate that the site is "under construction". As such, I believe this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). However, I'll get our in-house designer [Jin](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7/jin) to weigh in on this.

Answer (score 3):

Crikey, Lisa, that's hard to see. But you're right. But your monitor and colour settings must be set to show it stronger than mine for it to be annoying, or even generally noticeable, I have to say.